# Why is _IELinkClickByText() not clicking this link?

Tags: internet-explorer, autoit

I'm having trouble using `_IELinkclickbytext()`. I am trying to click a link :

```
<span class="actionLinks ">
<a class="actionItemName" href="analyze/addtoquickanalysis.do" title="Add to Quick Analysis">CPU <wbr></wbr>Util<wbr></wbr>izat<wbr></wbr>ion <wbr></wbr>%</a>
</span>
```

AutoIt code :

```
Local $sMyString = "CPU"
Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($oIE)
For $oLink In $oLinks
    Local $sLinkText = _IEPropertyGet($oLink, "innerText")
    If StringInStr($sLinkText, $sMyString) Then
        _IEAction($oLink, "click")
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
Next
```

Where did I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see the logic seems right to me.
You can try to login what linktext you are actually getting

```
Local $sMyString = "CPU"
Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($oIE)
For $oLink In $oLinks
    Local $sLinkText = _IEPropertyGet($oLink, "innerText")

    ConsoleWrite('current link text' & $sLinkText & @CRLF)

    If StringInStr($sLinkText, $sMyString) Then
       ConsoleWrite('found proper link ' & $sLinkText & @CRLF)
        _IEAction($oLink, "click")
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
Next
```

In this way you will see what is the actual problem. Is the link missing from _IELinkGetCollection or something else is happening.